# Upload, Retrieve PDF, DOC and images to SQL Server

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have the following code to upload data from anywhere on my computer into a column called `Documents` with datatype `nvarchar(255)` in a table in SQL Server as a file path.

How can I load file path to the `Document` column in a table and retrieve it when its needed when `Open` button click? [see screenshot below]

I want to accomplish something like this for each records

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLos1.png)

On `Save` button click save to the database file path

Here is the code I am trying to use

```
List<string> pdfFiles = new List<string>();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.CheckFileExists = true;
    openFileDialog.AddExtension = true;
    openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
    openFileDialog.Filter = "PDF files (*.pdf)|*.pdf";

    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        pdfFiles = new List<string>();

        foreach (string fileName in openFileDialog.FileNames)
            pdfFiles.Add(fileName);
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string installedPath = Application.StartupPath + "pdf";

    // Check whether folder path is exist
    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(installedPath))
    {
        // If not create new folder
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(installedPath);
    }

    // Save pdf files in installedPath
    foreach (string sourceFileName in pdfFiles)
    {
        string destinationFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(installedPath, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(sourceFileName));
        System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFileName, destinationFileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no question here.  Please provide a valid question that can be answered.

Comment: @ShaneRay I want browse load to the textbox and on Save Button Click,save it to the filed in the database and retrieve it when its needed

Comment: He looks like he asked a far reaching, but valid question "How can i load file path to the filed and retrieve it when i need it?"  albeit filled with language errors, but I suspect English is not the first language here.

Comment: Is the intention here to store just the file path to the database or the file contents? (edit: I just reread and it seems you just want to save the path) Have you ever saved anything to a SQL database before?  What have you tried other than the code above that does not do anything with a database?  When you say retrieve when needed.. what is the requirement there?  selected from a list?

Comment: @ShaneRay I want to store the file content to the database, .No i didn't save documents to MSSQL server from C# before I did using PHP and MYSQL but i am a newbie for C#. I want to save drawings of an Item to the database and print/Get it   anytime.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to store a PDF file content to the SQL database `navchar(255)` is not a good solution.  You should read up on the `varbinary` data type.

This link should give you some clue on where to start: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/a20beb/how-to-save-pdf-word-and-excel-files-into-the-database/

Comment: Thank you, I am on Winforms

Comment: Even though you are on win forms that is just the front end or UI.  The back end work of saving the data to the database should be the same or very similar.

Comment: @ShaneRay, Uploading file in win form and web form are different when you're trying to save it in remote database. In Web Form we use to save file on server and store only a path in the database. But in Win Form we cannot directly save the file on the server hard disk , we have to post in binary form.